# Open a push notification to specific tab on android tab group

Tags: android, tabs

I'm new to tabs and push notifications. I want my push notification to open up to a specific tab on my app.  I have been able to achieve this, but the tab bar is missing because of the way I have implemented the intent. I'm using the TabActivity to handle the tabs. Is there a way to write the intent so it will open up the app to a certain tab?

```
 private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {

    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String appname = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    Notification notification;
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,new Intent(context, FriendGroupActivity.class), 0);


    notification = new Notification(icon, message, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, appname, message, contentIntent);
    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);




}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the actual `Intent` you're launching with

```
new Intent(context, FriendGroupActivity.class)
```

you should just include more info either in the data URI or extras Bundle, that you then can use in your Activity's onCreate() to switch to the tab you care about

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I added `in.putExtra("tab", "tab4");` to my intent, then in my TabActivity had the app open to the intents `tab` if it existed.